# Detecting USB Connect/Disconnect without polling on GetMessage()

Tags: c++, usb

I want to detect insertion and removal of USB device. 
All solutions point to RegisterDeviceNotification and getting WM_DEVICECHANGE event.

What I understand is, I need to call GetMessage() so that I will get Event message and it can be processed through WndProc. 
Is there any way, where it will automatically generate an interrupt without polling on GetMessage().

Comment: You don't poll on `GetMessage()`: in Windows that is the usual way any event in a program is processed, so it shouldn't be any difference for this particular message. Other issue would be if you are doing a console program...

Comment: I am developing a non-GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

`GetMessage` is shown as an example. All message function in Window can be used with `WM_DEVICECHANGE`, including `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`.